# ValidationException when using injecting variables to boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I am transferring variables from one function to the other , where the final step is to use them as a part of a BOTO3 function.
I am getting the needed variable, and converting it to a STR type.

1. I tried to check the type of the output I'm getting, also tried to change it to Unicode (I'm familiar with the difference between str & Unicode).
2. check with hexdump to see if there are any secret hidden characters,
3. tried to save it to a file and reading from it,
4. compered the string I am generating and the one from the aws console - they are the same !
5. tried to change the formating method of the variables {} .format vs %s,
6. tried to update the aws cli \ python versions..
7. The annoying part is that when using the string from aws console, the BOTO3 function works perfectly. (so it is not a permission issue)

```
def describe_table():
    response = client.list_tables(
    )
    tablename = response['TableNames']

    for n in tablename:
        if 'tname' in n:
            print n
    return n


def tag_dynamo(AID):
    AID = '111222333'
    response = client.tag_resource(
        ResourceArn="arn:aws:dynamodb:region:%s:table/%s" % (AID, n),
            Tags=[
            {
                'Key': 'Key_name',
                'Value': 'value_state'
            }
            ]
        )
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the 
TagResource operation: Invalid TableArn: Invalid ResourceArn provided as input 
arn:aws:dynamodb:region:AID:table/TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: What is your "boto3" version?

Comment: The ARN string is invalid. You have not started the double quotes after ResourceARN=

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 you are correct. I fixed it in the question

Comment: Did you modify the error message to read `arn:aws:dynamodb:region:AID:table/TABLE_NAME` or was it literally that? Either way, you're supplying an invalid ARN.

Comment: @MayankPatel 
aws-cli/1.15.82 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.10.81

Comment: @jarmod I am aware of the invalid ARN.
It is modified to mask some details.
My question is why it happens , and if possible , how to solve it...

Comment: Change `return (n)` to `return n` for one thing. And include the rest of the code that connects these functions together. Right now, you do not show how `AID` is passed into the function and you do not show how `n` is populated.

Comment: @jarmod (n) fixed. 
n is received by     response = client.list_tables(
    )
AID is received properly = it is the account id. it is received as an int type, and in my tests I tried to change it  to be str \unicode as well

Comment: You should include all the relevant code. Talking about it in comments is not the same thing. There's a bug in your code, almost certainly, and we really can't help without seeing all the relevant code.

Comment: In your ARN, you should replace region with region name like us-east-1